# Property file reloading without restarting jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I want the property files changes to take effect without having to restart the jboss server.

My piece of code goes like this

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy;

public class Myclass{
private static PropertiesConfiguration configure;
try {
        configure = new PropertiesConfiguration("MyProperties.properties");
        configure.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
        configure.setAutoSave(true);
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

But this is not working until i restart the server.

Can anyone plz help me out?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Where are those classes from, e.g. `PropertiesConfiguration`? As far as I know it's not part of the JDK...

Comment: I have these three import statements on top

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this file is inside a jar file. Properties files don't keep changes inside a jar and therefore no `FileChangedReloadingStrategy` will be triggered.

Try to have the file outside a jar.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!!
but the file is not in the jar..rather it's in the jboss/jboss-4.2.3.GA\config

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing around with the code you mentioned and giving the absolute path of the properties file `MyProperties.properties` worked

```
configure = new PropertiesConfiguration("C:\\MyProperties.properties");
```

Not sure if this is a bug in the library or its the way it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

No. It wouldn't be working even though your properties file outside jar. Your properites file will be with your class code packed into a running code, such as .EAR file, and deployed on sever specific Directory before you start JBOSS. Any changes on your original properties file will not effect anymore, unless you pack it again and deploy on Server once more.